# String to Array based on closing double quotes

Tags: ruby

I am trying to convert this string:

```
'"This is a normal string","This, has a comma inside it"'
```

into an array by `string.split(",")`, but instead of getting two elements in array, I get three:

```
["This is a normal string","This","has a comma inside it"]
```

Any suggestion on a possible work around? How do I split the string on closing double quotes instead of a comma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think the scan method might be the easiest:

```
s.scan(/"(.*?)"/).flatten #=> ["This is a normal string", "This, has a comma inside it"]
```

Else, just make sure the split comma is preceded by a quote character:

```
s.split(/(?<="),/) #=> ["\"This is a normal string\"", "\"This, has a comma inside it\""]
```

I still prefer the first method as it also removes the quotes around the string.

Finally, if you have very tricky string with escaped quotation marks you can add a check to see if the quotation mark is followed by a comma or the end of the string:

```
s = '"This is a \"normal\" string","This, has a comma inside it"'
s.scan(/"(.*?)"(?:,|\z)/).flatten #=> ["This is a \\\"normal\\\" string", "This, has a comma inside it"]
```